# Refine Probability Distribution Script

Tags: python

I have this python script that helps me with generating random combinations based upon odds, it could be used for harness racing when we have to pick the winning horse in 7 consecutive races.

Now I would like to refine this script a bit more to my wishes if possible. As already said the script now spits out random numbers based upon odds. Now I would like that to be done in a bit more distinguished manner. I don't want combinations with too many numbers corresponding with low odds. In other words, I want the script to select randomly 4 of the 7 races and come back with a random number with higher odds (+20%) for each of the 4 races. For the 3 remaining races it must give me numbers each with less than a 10% probability.

This all goes way beyond my own python knowledge so I was hoping to receive some help here.

Thx in advance for all useful input.

```
import bpy
import random

scene = bpy.context.scene



def get_random_value(race):
    """
    Function which returns a String containing random values based on the given probability distribution
    """
    
    # Generates an Array [1,2,3,...,amount_of_race_participants]
    numberList = [x+1 for x in range(len(race))]

    temp = ' '
    for x in random.choices(numberList, weights=race, k=1):
        temp = temp + str(x) + ","
    temp1 = temp[0:-1] + ''

    return temp1

def generate_text(iteration, race):
    """
    Creates a Text Object with random content and a location based on the input value
    Also gives race odds to the get_random_value function, which is used for the probability distribution
    """

    # Create Curve with text content
    font_curve = bpy.data.curves.new(type="FONT",name="Font Curve")
    font_curve.body = get_random_value(race)
    # Put Curve into Object and link it to the scene
    font_obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name="Font Object", object_data=font_curve)
    scene.collection.objects.link(font_obj)

    # Set location of Object
    font_obj.location = (0,-iteration,0)

    return font_obj

def generate_n_texts():
    """
    Creates a variable amount of Texts objects and returns them
    """
    
    races = [
    [5, 58, 4, 4, 8, 3, 3, 2, 5, 1, 6, 1 ],
    [3, 4, 6, 5, 19, 4, 4, 2, 2, 21, 11, 19 ],
    [12, 3, 6, 14, 6, 8, 4, 3, 18, 2, 1, 23 ],
    [15, 4, 23, 4, 29, 4, 3, 5, 8, 5 ],
    [9, 2, 12, 3, 4, 43, 5, 4, 3, 7, 1, 7 ],
    [3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 61, 3, 2, 7, 11, 1 ],
    [10, 3, 13, 31, 6, 14, 6, 9, 4, 2, 2 ]
    ]


    font_objs = []
   
    # enumerate goes through the array race and gives us an element and its index
    for iteration, race in enumerate(races):
        font_objs.append((generate_text(iteration, race), race))

    # Font Objects includes tuples of font objects and their respective probability distribution
    # like this [(obj, race), (obj, race), ...]
    return font_objs


# Generate font_objs list before definint recalculate_text() so the function can use the list
font_objs = generate_n_texts()

def recalculate_text(scene):
    """
    Sets the bodies of the font_objs list to a random number
    """

    #Remove seed to get a different number for every frame, even when revisiting a frame
    random.seed(scene.frame_current)

    for obj, race in font_objs:
        obj.data.body = get_random_value(race)
        
def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(recalculate_text)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(recalculate_text)


register()
```

Comment: `I want the script to select randomly 4 of the 7 races and come back with a random number with higher odds (+20%) for each of the 4 races. For the 3 remaining races it must give me numbers each with less than a 10% probability.` - Totally unclear. After you randomly choose 4 out of 7, what do the remaining 3 have to do with anything? You've already made your random choice and left them "out of the game". Consider rephrasing your question.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I'll give it another try in a different way. Hope that makes it clear. As said this script is made for harness racing, we have to pick the winning horse in 7 consecutive races.  In most cases the favorite horse odds wise wins the race. But of course not always, that makes horse betting unpredictable. So we have to include some outsiders in our coupon, but not too many. You wrote ' After you randomly choose 4 out of 7', that is incorrect, I want the script to pick 4 of the 7 races randomly where it looks for high odds horses and return 1 of them. (1/2)

Comment: For the remaining 3 races I want the script to give me 3 low-odds horse numbers. So every ticket/coupon contains 4 +20% odds horses & 3 -10% horses. Hope I made it more clear now. (2/2)